# C# Windows Forms ToolStrip and MenuStrip memory leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, toolstrip, menustrip

I'm creating a Windows Forms app in C# (.NET 4.7.2), I just added a ToolStrip and a MenuStrip.
If I run the application the memory usage jumps to 600mb, too much for a Windows Forms application with only a ToolStrip and a MenuStrip, if I delete them both memory usage returns to normal .
I did some research and found that there is a memory leak in ToolStrip and MenuStrip, I also tried this ([ToolStrip memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865741/toolstrip-memory-leak)), but didn't work.
How this can be fixed?

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{

    if (disposing)
    {
        var overflow = toolStrip1.OverflowButton.DropDown as ToolStripOverflow;
        if (overflow != null)
            overflow.Dispose();
    }


    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Many things are cached, so the exact amount of "leak" is hard to determine. Use a profiler for that.

Comment: The Q&A you linked is from 2009. -- Did you add Images to your MenuStrip or ToolStrip items? Do you have images somewhere else? Note that compressed Images are decompressed when used in a UI, so a 500k image can turn into a monster, depending on how much the content can be compressed. Use `16x16` Images for your menus.

Comment: I'm using 2 images in the menu, I'll try with no images

Comment: Remove what you have added in the `Dispose()` override. Those components are already taken care of when `components.Dispose();` is called.

Comment: I tried a 16 x 16 and 32 x 32 images and worked, thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue but my images are 16x16...  was that your only issue?